# Is it possible to pass an iterable to the ylabel parameter in pandas.DataFrame.plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

Consider the following piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,4))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
df.plot(
    ...:                 subplots=True,
    ...:                 ylabel=("a","b","c","d"),
    ...:                 ax=ax[:4],
    ...:             )
```

The output is a figure with 4 `Axes` with the same `ylabel` (which is `("a","b","c","d")`)  for all the 4 `Axes`.

What I would like to achieve is the following

```
y_label = "a" <- for axes[0,0],  
y_label = "b" <- for axes[0,1], 
y_label = "c" <- for axes[1,0], 
y_label = "d" <- for axes[1,1],
```

At the moment, this can be accomplished by exploiting `Axes.set_ylabel()` method inside a `for` loop but I wonder if it is possible to pass an iterable directly to the `ylabel` argument of `pandas.DataFrame.plot`.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) is clear that the type of ylabel is `label` but, it falls short in clearly explain what `label` type is.

Comment: Can you also provide a constructor to generate `ax`?

Comment: Done! Sorry, I mis-copied. Thanks for the heads-up,

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear, the parameter accepts a single value:

> **ylabel**  label, optional
>
> Name to use for the ylabel on y-axis. Default will show no ylabel, or the y-column name for planar plots.

You can use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,4))
df.plot(subplots=True, ax=ax)

ylabels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for label, a in zip(ylabels, ax.flat):
    a.set_ylabel(label)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: 1. What type is `label`? Is it `str`, `int`, ... or is it a class object? What is that?
2. As stated in my question, I wonder if it is possible to pass an iterable. Can `label` type be an iterable?

Comment: It's any object, but will be converted to `str`. If you pass a list you will get the string representation of the list (not what you want).

Comment: It cannot be any object. If you pass e.g. a `pd.DataFrame` object it won't work.

Comment: Could be, I have not tested all objects ;) But the idea is that you should pass a string.

Comment: It is. I tested it.

Comment: So I guess the summary is **no you cannot pass any iterable**, you should pass a single value, preferentially a string.

Comment: Apparently it is. But it is not clear what are the limitation to such a "single value". The documentation says it is a label but then we are back to my original statement about what a `label` is supposed to be. Do you still think the documentation is clear? :)